# problem with git on a unity project

Tags: unity, git

I tried to version control my project folder with git. When it came to pull the project from the repository, though, something went wrong: apparently scripts are missing and the prefabs and kind of all the graphical elements appear to be pinkish. Does anybody know how to fix this?

This is the .gitignore I'm using at the moment:

```
Temp/
Obj/
UnityGenerated/
Library/

ExportedObj/
*.svd
*.userprefs
*.csproj
*.pidb
*.suo
*.sln
*.user
*.unityproj
*.booproj

.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor` and make sure that the `Version Control Mode` property is set to `Meta Files`, not `Disabled`.

Starting from Unity 4.2 you can also set the `Asset Serialization Mode` property to `Force Text` without needing a Pro license, which is supposed to work better with version control too.

And here is the gitignore that I use:

```
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/

# Autogenerated VS/MD solution and project files
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.apk
*.sln.DotSettings.user
*.suo
*.userprefs
*.pidb
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Unity 4.3 you also have to enable External option from preferences, so full setup process looks like:

1. **Enable `External` option in `Edit(or Unity on Mac) → Preferences → Packages → Repository`**
2. Switch to `Hidden Meta Files` in `Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Version Control Mode`
3. Switch to `Force Text` in `Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Asset Serialization Mode`
4. Save scene and project from `File` menu

More information about keeping Unity Project under source control you can find in [this post](http://developers.nravo.com/mastering-unity-project-folder-structure-level-0-vcs).

Comment: The URI for the link at the end looks like it has gone lost. Where did you mean it to point to?

Comment: Thanks for pointing on this, here is link http://developers.nravo.com/mastering-unity-project-folder-structure-level-0-vcs/#.Uvz2nUKSzbg

Comment: it's not a direct answer to this question but thanks for mentioning "Force Text" serialization because it's useful for version control